# SQL Column Name as Row Value

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have a table with 'Region', 'Target' and 'Actual' columns as below.

| Region | Target | Actual |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 10 | 1 |
| B | 20 | 2 |

I want to change this table with my query so that the target and actual columns are in rows as follows.

| Region | Type | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Target | 10 |
| A | Actual | 1 |
| B | Target | 20 |
| B | Actual | 2 |

How should I prepare my query for this or which way should I use? thanks in advance.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a UNION for this:

```
select region, 'Target' as type, target as amount
from the_table
union all
select region, 'Actual' as type, actual
from the_table
order by region, type desc
```

Another option is to use a lateral join to construct two rows out of the columns:

```
select t.region, x.*
from the_table t
  cross join lateral (
    values ('Target', target), ('Actual', actual)
  ) as x(type, amount)
order by t.region, x.type desc;
```

Both queries are 100% standard ANSI SQL. However not all database products support lateral joins or the `VALUES` clause like that.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `UNPIVOT` with single access to the table which does exactly what is described:

> ```
> select /*+ gather_plan_statistics */ *
> from t
> unpivot(
>   Amount for Type_ in (
>     Target as 'Target'
>     , Actual as 'Actual'
>   )
> )
> ```
>
> ```
> REGION | TYPE_  | AMOUNT
> :----- | :----- | -----:
> A      | Target |     10
> A      | Actual |      1
> B      | Target |     20
> B      | Actual |      2
> ```

> ```
> | PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT                                                                               |
> | :---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | SQL_ID  9rr5wa2yjxf42, child number 0                                                           |
> | -------------------------------------                                                           |
> | select /*+ gather_plan_statistics */ * from t unpivot(   Amount for                             |
> | Type_ in (     Target as 'Target'     , Actual as 'Actual'   ) )                                |
> |                                                                                                 |
> | Plan hash value: 605266837                                                                      |
> |                                                                                                 |
> | ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | | Id  | Operation           | Name | Starts | E-Rows | A-Rows |   A-Time   | Buffers | Reads  | |
> | ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT    |      |      1 |        |      4 |00:00:00.01 |       2 |      1 | |
> | |*  1 |  VIEW               |      |      1 |      4 |      4 |00:00:00.01 |       2 |      1 | |
> | |   2 |   UNPIVOT           |      |      1 |        |      4 |00:00:00.01 |       2 |      1 | |
> | |   3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL| T    |      1 |      2 |      2 |00:00:00.01 |       2 |      1 | |
> | ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> |                                                                                                 |
> | Predicate Information (identified by operation id):                                             |
> | ---------------------------------------------------                                             |
> |                                                                                                 |
> |    1 - filter("unpivot_view_005"."AMOUNT" IS NOT NULL)                                          |
> |                                                                                                 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=bfedc53bb27121045229a7bbc59bdb0d)*